# does Excel copy only visible cells when a filter is enabled

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

According to MS doc

- excel 2007 https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Copy-visible-cells-only-6e3a1f01-2884-4332-b262-8b814412847e
- excel 2013 https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Copy-and-paste-visible-cells-only-6f655372-4ea0-4221-bf68-272422419b59

It said

> If you copy a range of cells that has hidden or filtered rows, Excel includes the hidden or filtered cells when you paste it somewhere else."

But actually I found when you enable a filter in a sheet, Excel only copies those visible cells no matter they are hidden by a filter or manually.

And I found Excel 2011 behaves differently, it always copies invisible cells no matter a filter is enabled or not.

Can someone confirm this? or do I misunderstand the MS doc?

Comment: what is your actual problem behind this question? Does it behave differently then you expected? Please note that after doing the selection you can always change between visible / all at home tab - find and select - special form.

Comment: I am developing a product that reads an Excel file and works like Excel, so I want to know what is its behaviour.

Comment: presuming you use Excel object model, e.g.: `Range("A5:D50")` will contain all cells, while `Range("A5:D50").SpecialCells(xlCellsVisible)` will contain only visible cells. That's the same for all versions.

Answer (score 2):

Filters in Excel 2013 are a little confusing: Excel selects a bunch of cells according to the filter, and then minimizes the height of rows that don't have a selection / meet the filter criteria.

You can actually resize those rows to see that the data are still there, it's just that the cells aren't selected. Set up a simple filter and take a close look, can you see how Excel has 'shrunk' the redundant rows?

So you need to be really careful when copying and pasting onto adjacent columns. But if you copy the results of a filter onto a new worksheet, or onto rows beneath your filter area, you should find that Excel only copies the selected cells. I would post some pictures but I can't because my reputation isn't high enough.